# In what order is the blockheader hashed?

Tags: hash, block-header

In what order are the hash of the previous block, the root of the merkle and the nonce hashed to produce the hash of the next bitcoin block?

Answer (score 1):

They are hashed in the order they appear in the [network serialisation](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#block):

> #### block
>
> The **block** message is sent in response to a getdata message which requests transaction information from a block hash.
>
> | Field Size | Description | Data type | Comments |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 4 | version | int32_t | Block version information (note, this is signed) |
> | 32 | prev_block | char[32] | The hash value of the previous block this particular block references |
> | 32 | merkle_root | char[32] | The reference to a Merkle tree collection which is a hash of all transactions related to this block |
> | 4 | timestamp | uint32_t | A Unix timestamp recording when this block was created (Currently limited to dates before the year 2106!) |
> | 4 | bits | uint32_t | The calculated difficulty target being used for this block |
> | 4 | nonce | uint32_t | The nonce used to generate this block… to allow variations of the header and compute different hashes |
> | 1+ | txn_count | var_int | Number of transaction entries |
> | ? | txns | tx[] | Block transactions, in format of "tx" command |

The block header is hashed. So from version to nonce inclusive.

---

Related:

- [What data is hashed to produce the block hash?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/107826/13866)
- [What are the components of the raw block shown in this image?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/114108/13866)
- https://medium.com/hackergirl/how-to-calculate-the-hash-of-a-block-in-bitcoin-8f6aebb0dc6d